# blk_update_request: I/0 error, dev fd0, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ)

Tags: linux, partitioning, debian, grub

I have implemented A/B partitions on a Debian system to easily be able to upgrade in case of a failed upgrade. I have both `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sda2` as bootable with Debian 11 and can switch between them with the grub loader.

Everything seems to run fine, except when I run `fdisk -l` and get the following errors. I'm unsure what they mean or how to go about solving them:

```
[ 322.588154] blk_update_request: I/0 error, dev fd0, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 322.632137] blk_update_request: I/0 error, dev fd0, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0

Disk /dev/sda: 32 GiB, 34359738368 bytes, 67108864 sectors
Disk model: Virtual Disk
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xf445b7ca

Device     Boot    Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *        2048 19531775 19529728  9.3G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       19531776 39063551 19531776  9.3G 83 Linux
/dev/sda3       39063552 67106815 28043264 13.4G 83 Linux
```

Comment: Looks like a VM. Can try to disable the emulated floppy drive(s). Or blacklist the `floppy` module / driver on the guest.

Comment: @TomYan it does not have a floppy drive attached in Hyper-V VM.

Comment: @TomYan I blacklisted floppy which has stopped the errors from showing. Weird they were showing at all though.

Answer (score 2):

`fd0` usually refers to a floppy drive. If your system does have a floppy drive that doesn't contain a floppy this might popup because the floppy drive tries to access a floppy but can't.

If you don't have any need for a floppy drive consider removing it to get rid of the error or pass along a device. As your partitions are on `/dev/sda` you should be able to run `fdisk -l /dev/sda` to just get paritions on that device. You might have to check the man page of your particular fdisk implementation.

Comment: It is on a Hyper-V VM that does not have a floppy drive attached.

Comment: Does it not feature a floppy drive that's visible in the VM configuration or is there no floppy drive in the BIOS/UEFI visible? Make sure to check both locations. At least with VMware there are version where you might not have a floppy drive configured for the VM but it will still be available in the BIOS and thus show up in the OS.